# Push notifications for Phonegap Build

Tags: android, html, cordova, notifications

I have an HTML Android app made with PhoneGap Build.

I'd like an Andrid user to recieve a Push Notification on the notification bar (even if the app is closed) every day at the same time (for example at 10:00) with the text like "open me". When I click on the notification the app must opens I should be navigated to one of my app pages. Is it possible to do with the PhoneGap Notifications plugin? or any other way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Unless you have a *really* good reason for this, please **don't**. Unless it's an app that generates alarms or is required for an enterprise app that isn't distributed to the public, this is considered spammy behavior. Goodness knows that apps that do this do *not* last long on my device.

Answer (score 0):

1) In GCMIntentService Class:

```
    private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage");        
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String notiMsg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
String message = notiMsg;`enter code here`


long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
int iwhen = (int )when;
// define sound URI, the sound to be played when there's a notification
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent,0);

// this is it, we'll build the notification!
// in the addAction method, if you don't want any icon, just set the first param to 0
NotificationCompat.Builder mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setSound(soundUri)
    .setWhen(when)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(iwhen, mNotification.build());
}
```

2) Create NotificationReceiver Class :

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    super.init(); 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
AlertDialog.Builder alert_box=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert_box.setTitle("Title");
    alert_box.setMessage("New message received, would you like to open it.");
    alert_box.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        login();
       }
      });
    alert_box.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
      });

    alert_box.show();

    if (Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE!=null) {
        Log.i("NotificationReceiver","Clear all notification");
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancelAll();
    }
    }

public void login() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationReceiver.this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i("NotificationReceiver","onB`enter code here`ackPressed");     
}}
```

3) Create NewActivity Class with specific url:

```
public class NewActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i("NewActivity","NewActivityAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.init(); 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/notification_main.html");
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i("NewActivity","onBackPressed");       
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a background service that includes only a thread that periodically create and send a notification. Refer to the official Android documentation to understand hire to do it.

Why are you using PhoneGap if the only platform will be Android? For single platform app it is much better to use dedicated SDK. On the contrary, if you need to port your app to iOS, the notifications cannot be managed via PhoneGap API, you need to use native programming.

Finally I agree with user.sc, I would delete the app at the first notification :-) But I don't want to syndicate your reasons to do that